# I have a list choice = [[1,1],[2,2]]. How do I access a value? I tried choice[[1]], but it gives an error

Tags: python, list

```
choice = [[1,1],[1,1]]
```

I want to access a value in choice, but if I try `choice[[1]]`, it gives me an error. How do I get a value? Also, how do I change one? Thanks.

Comment: What value do you want to access?

Comment: `choice[index of the list you want to get][index of the item in THAT list you want]`

Comment: `choice[0][1]` to access the second element of the first 'choice', `choice[1][0] = 0` to change the value of the first element of the second 'choice'.

Answer (score 1):

```
choice = [[1,2],[4,5]]
value = choice[0]    # This will return the list [1,2]
value = choice[0][1] # This will return the value 2 from the first list
value = choice[1][0] # This will return the value 4 from the second list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
choice = [[1,1],[1,1]]
choice[0][0] # 1
```

It's an equivalent of:

```
choice = [[1,1],[1,1]]
tmp_var = choice[0] # [1, 1]
your_result = tmp_var[0] # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are dealing with a double array. If you want to access [[**1**,1],[1,1]], you will have to access it by

```
    choice[0][0]
```

[[1,1],[**1**,1]] will be accessed by

```
    choice[1][0]
```

...and so on!

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

First, The code for that is [1][1]

Second, arrays start at 0 so if you want the first value it's [0][0]

Answer (score 0):

You can access individual values by double addressing, ex.

```
>> choice[0][0]
1
>> choice[1][0]
2
```

and change them the same way as changing variable values:

```
>> choice
[[1, 1], [2, 2]]
>> choice[1][0] = 6
>> choice
[[1, 1], [6, 2]]
```